# How to keep matched row on top of other rows in table using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm using Smart table i want to keep matched rows on top of other rows in table using angularjs(1), in my case i have been matching string from table column, on the basis of matched string I'm changing row background color, but i want to show those colored rows on top of the other rows, so that I'm able see matched rows instantly.

it is worked if i sort like below, but it affect only current page, i want display all matched rows to top of other rows irrespective pagination and all.

```
<tr ng-repeat="emp in employees | orderBy:set_color" ng-style="set_color(emp)">
```

how i can achieve this. if you want more info please take a look at this link

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
  
      .controller('employeeController', function ($scope) {
     
   var employees = [{
    "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "City": "Berlin",
    "Country": "Germany"
  }, {
    "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
    "City": "Luleå",
    "Country": "Sweden"
  }, {
    "Name": "Blauer See Delikatessen",
    "City": "Mannheim",
    "Country": "Germany"
  }, {
    "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
    "City": "Strasbourg",
    "Country": "France"
  }, {
    "Name": "Bólido Comidas preparadas",
    "City": "Madrid",
    "Country": "Spain"
  }, {
    "Name": "Bon app'",
    "City": "Marseille",
    "Country": "France"
  }, {
    "Name": "Bottom-Dollar Marketse",
    "City": "Tsawassen",
    "Country": "Canada"
  }, {
    "Name": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
    "City": "Buenos Aires",
    "Country": "Argentina"
  }, {
    "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
    "City": "México D.F.",
    "Country": "Mexico"
  }, {
    "Name": "Chop-suey Chinese",
    "City": "Bern",
    "Country": "Switzerland"
  }, {
    "Name": "Comércio Mineiro",
    "City": "São Paulo",
    "Country": "Brazil"
  }];
      $scope.employees=employees;
      
      $scope.set_color = function (emp) {
                    var inputString = emp.Country;
                    for (i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
                        var findme = "France";
                        if (inputString.indexOf(findme) > -1) {
                            return { 'background-color': '#FFCCCB' }
                        }
                    }
                }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="employeeController">
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:40px;">
            <div class="row">
                {{error}}
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>City</th>
                                <th>Country</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody >
                            <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees" ng-style="set_color(emp)">
                                <td>{{emp.Name}}</td>
                                <td>{{emp.City}}</td>
                                <td>{{emp.Country}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank you

Comment: Add a property to the objects and write a custom sort filter that sorts first by that property

Comment: i want only matched rows comes first in table.

Comment: Right and you would want a sort function for that. Create a plunker demo can give you idea how

Comment: could you please give an example if possible.

Comment: Big issue though is you would also have to write custom sorts for all the columns that have sorting also

Comment: Really basic sort example https://jsfiddle.net/9vywy0vy/

Comment: okay i will try, thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: please see above demo. i want to display those matched row from top and non matched rows should display below them in table

Comment: to support this across pagination using smart table is not trivial and would require you to write your own pagination filtering

Comment: @PrashanthOlekar if you need matched results from another page i.e from all employees in database, then you have to send the matched results of other pages from your server whenever the word needs to be matched changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With AngularJS i believe I would choose this option:

**HTML**

orderBy can take multiple filters

```
 <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees | orderBy: [sort, 'Name']" 
     ng-class="{'matched': emp.matched }">
```

**JS**

```
var findme = "France";
$scope.sort = (emp) => {
   emp.matched = emp.Country.indexOf(findme) > -1; 
   return !emp.matched; 
}
```

See working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kraaness/vft90229/

Answer (score 4):

You could treat the `std` as a list, and sorting it taking into account the similarities. For example you could do the following:

```
// This function will return a list with the matching elements first,
// and the non matching after.

$ordered = function(findme) {
    var values = Object.values(std);
    var matching = values.filter(e => e === findme);
    var notMatching = values.filter(e => e !== findme);
    return matching.concat(notMatching);
}
```

And then in the html you could do the following:

```
<tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="std in students" ng-style="set_color(std)">
               <td ng-repeat="x in ordered()">{{x}}</td>
         </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm more familiar with angular 2, 4 and 5, so forget me if calling a function within the ng-repeat is not allowed. Other solution would be to store that list as a variable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have added demo, in that i had matched two rows. but i want those two matched rows on top of other rows. even in pagination also if more rows matched from another pagination i want sort them order wise from top of other rows

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

**HTML**

```js
// I used `B` as `std.Name` for example in my code:

function matchRowByName() {
  $.each($('tr[ng-repeat="std in students"'), function() {
    if ($(this).find('td').first().text() === "B") {
      $('table').prepend($(this));
      $(this).addClass('matched');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="std in students" ng-style="set_color(std)">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>a@test.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="std in students" ng-style="set_color(std)">
    <td>B</td>
    <td>b@test.com</td>
  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="std in students" ng-style="set_color(std)">
    <td>C</td>
    <td>c@test.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**Online demo(jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/q576sx1e/2/)

Comment: I have added demo, in that i had matched two rows. but i want those two matched rows on top of other rows. even in pagination also if more rows matched from another pagination i want sort them order wise from top of other rows.